# While loop not working as expected for randomly picking new string from list

Tags: c#, wpf

Being a complete beginner I think I've done something seriously wrong within my WPF application as the while loop I've incorporated doesn't work as planned.

```
List<string> alreadyUsedReagents = new List<string>(new string[] {});
List<string> alreadyUsedMetals = new List<string>(new string[] { });

List<string> reagents = new List<string>(new string[]{
        "Hexaaqua ion",
        "Dilute NaOH",
        "Excess NaOH",
        "Dilute NH₃",
        "Excess NH₃",
        "Salt",
        "Na₂CO₃",
        "HCl"});

public void RefreshReagents()
{
    alreadyUsedReagents.Clear();
}

public string CycleThroughReagents()
{
    bool keepinLoop = true;
    string chosenReagent = null;

    while (keepinLoop == true)
    {
        int r = rnd.Next(reagents.Count);
        string pickedReagent = (string)reagents[r];


        if (!alreadyUsedReagents.Contains(pickedReagent))
        {
            alreadyUsedReagents.Add(pickedReagent);
            chosenReagent = pickedReagent;
            keepinLoop = false;
        }

        if (alreadyUsedReagents.Count == 8)
        {
            RefreshReagents();
            keepinLoop = false;
        }
        else
        {
            keepinLoop = true;
        }
    }

    return chosenReagent;
}
```

The while loop is suppose to loop through and return a `reagent` that has not been already used, all the used reagents are suppose to be stored within the `alreadyUsedReagents` list which the while loop analyses, then this `CycleThroughReagents` method is used within my `SetButtonContent` method which sets the button properties.

```
public void SetButtonContent(string ChosenMetal, TextBlock reagentText, TextBlock transMetalText,
        Button opt1, Button opt2, Button opt3, Button opt4, Button opt5, Button opt6, Button opt7, Button opt8)
{
    string pickedMetal = "Cobalt";
    string pickedReagent = CycleThroughReagents();

    reagentText.Text = pickedReagent;
    transMetalText.Text = pickedMetal;
}
```

A switch function is implemented within this method which sets the tag of a specific button to 'correct' if the button matches the reagent set.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    GameControl _GameControl = new GameControl();
    public string chosenMetal;
    int amtLeft = 8;


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        chosenMetal = _GameControl.CycleThroughMetals();
        _GameControl.SetButtonContent(chosenMetal,ReagentAdded, transMetal, Opt1, Opt2, Opt3, Opt4, Opt5, Opt6, Opt7, Opt8);

        Opt1.Click += HandleButtonClicks;
        Opt2.Click += HandleButtonClicks;
        Opt3.Click += HandleButtonClicks;
        Opt4.Click += HandleButtonClicks;
        Opt5.Click += HandleButtonClicks;
        Opt6.Click += HandleButtonClicks;
        Opt7.Click += HandleButtonClicks;
        Opt8.Click += HandleButtonClicks;  
    }

    public void SwitchMetals()
    {
        chosenMetal = _GameControl.CycleThroughMetals();
        _GameControl.RefreshReagents(); //method which clears the 'alreadyUsedReagents' list
        _GameControl.SetButtonContent(chosenMetal, ReagentAdded, transMetal, Opt1, Opt2, Opt3, Opt4, Opt5, Opt6, Opt7, Opt8);
    }

    private void HandleButtonClicks(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = sender as Button;
        CheckForCorrect(button);

    }

    public void CheckForCorrect(Button button)
    {
        if ((string)button.Tag == "correct" && amtLeft != 0)
        {
            amtLeft -= 1;
            MessageBox.Show("You guessed correct!");
            _GameControl.SetButtonContent(chosenMetal, ReagentAdded, transMetal, Opt1, Opt2, Opt3, Opt4, Opt5, Opt6, Opt7, Opt8);
            button.IsEnabled = false;
        }

        if ((string)button.Tag != "correct")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Oops!");
        }

        else if (amtLeft == 0)
          SwitchMetals();


    }
}
```

Then the above method is then used in the `MainWindow` to originally set the buttons and reagent text, and then the click method is used to see if the button clicked is the correct for the specific reagent that is set, and if it is then a new reagent is set. The problem I'm having is that it seems that I've completely messed up my code with the way I handle the looping and setting of the reagents, as when the reagent is displayed on the screen after each click sometimes the `TextBlock` appears blank and uses a previously used reagent. Any help would be seriously appreciated and I'm sorry in advance for including so much code sample but I'm seriously stumped on what to do from here.

Comment: I can't stop reading `keepinLoop` as Keep Loopin'

Comment: @CoderDennis hahaha yeah I can see why, I'm probably making a ton of rookie mistakes and doing bad programming practice but usually doing projects like this helps me learn stuff properly.

Comment: Any reason you have a `string` array in your `List<string>`?

Comment: @MattRowland no not that I can think of, what part are you on about?

Comment: The very top code that you posted. The `List<string> alreadyUsedReagents = new List<string>(new string[] {});` Could be changed to `List<string> alreadyUsedReagents = new List<string>();` along with the other Lists you are using.

Comment: I haven't read your code but your description suggests that you're doing it all wrong.  Why remember the items that have been selected already when you can just remember the ones that haven't?  Start by putting all the items into a second list, select one randomly using a `Random` instance and then remove that item from the list.  Keep doing that until the list is empty and then refill it if required.

Comment: @CallumHoughton Keep Learnin' and don't be afraid of rookie mistakes. We've all been there.

Comment: @MattRowland nope, I just initialized the list incorrectly thanks for point it out though I just corrected the mistake.

Comment: @jmcilhinney that's essentially the answer I posted.

Comment: @CoderDennis, There were no comments or answers when I wrote my comment but I was having connection issues so much activity had occurred by the time it actually posted.

Comment: @jmcilhinney no worries. Turns out it was a good suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this without any loop at all if instead of keeping track of `alreadyUsedReagents` you kept a list of `unusedReagents`.

`RefreshReagents()` then populates `unusedReagents` with the whole list.

`CycleThroughReagents()` picks one at random, removes it from `unusedReagents` and returns it.

Call `RefreshReagents()` whenever `unusedReagents` is empty.

Comment: That sounds much cleaner than the solution I have at the moment, I'll try it in the morning. Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 4):

Just looking at the while loop, it seems that this piece:

```
if (!alreadyUsedReagents.Contains(pickedReagent))
{
    alreadyUsedReagents.Add(pickedReagent);
    chosenReagent = pickedReagent;
    keepinLoop = false;
}
```

should be doing `break`. The way it is currently working does not prevent further iterations of the loop, as value that you set here in `keepinloop` can be overridden by the if/else below. So try replacing the line

```
keepinLoop = false;
```

with

```
break;
```

That should fix your loop.

**Update.** Actually instead of using some made up flag to control your loop, it might be a better idea to use some real condition, like the number of used reagents for example:

```
while (alreadyUsedReagents.Count != 8)
{
    int r = rnd.Next(reagents.Count);
    string pickedReagent = (string)reagents[r];

    if (!alreadyUsedReagents.Contains(pickedReagent))
    {
        alreadyUsedReagents.Add(pickedReagent);
        chosenReagent = pickedReagent;
        break;
    }
}
RefreshReagents();

if (chosenReagent == null)
{
    // make sure to come up with some default
    // or your method will return null in some cases
}
```

Comment: And if you are doing that you should just set the while to loop on true. `while (true)` since you aren't using `keepinLoop` anymore.

Comment: The next thing the OP will need to handle is when you go back into `CycleThroughReagents()` and `alreadyUsedReagents.Count == 8`, it will return a null string.

Comment: Thank you!, that's fixed the issue of the TextBlock display being blank and using previously used reagents

Comment: @evanb, then perhaps the best way then is to do something like `while (count != 8)`. Actually let me update the answer with that. And mention your observation about null as well